# How do I read the fields in a csv file and load their values into variables?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Basic 10, and am attempting to convert an
old VB6 program. How do I read a csv file and load the fields into
individual VB10 fields?

Answer (score 0):

Define a class with the matching fields.  Instantiate that class and set its values to what's in the CSV file.  There are libraries that can help parse the CSV file, such as [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) or you can take a more manual approach using the [System.Io.File Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) and string manipulation to parse the CSV file.